# C Language - Call function from object file

Tags: c, function, object

I have a little problem while compiling an Eclipse project.
I have a file that needs to call functions present in an already compiled files (.o files).

Init.c

```
#include Init.h
void Init() {
    InitA();
    InitB();
    InitC();
    InitD();
}
```

Init.h

```
extern void InitA();
extern void InitB();
extern void InitC();
extern void InitD();
void Init();
```

And the 4 functions are present in the object file motor_init.o

I would like to know if it is possible to call these functions and how.

Comment: Yes. it is possible.

Comment: Do you know how i could do that ?

Comment: @Neurchack I have no experience with Eclipse (being an Emacs/Command line person), but I assume you could hook something up with the linker settings. If not, someone with Eclipse knowledge can step in ;)

Comment: So you think it is just a question of linker ?

Comment: One init function is bad. Five is terrible.

Comment: "Five" is terrible ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's what `.o` files ar for, containing function. You have already defined the signatures, so all you'll need to do is is create `init.o` and link them together into your final product.

if you're using gcc as compiler:

```
gcc -c init.c
gcc init.o motor_init.o -o output
```

Sorry i don't know specifics about eclipse plugins.

Also, if you have it, i would recommend using `motor_init.h`.

Comment: I don't have the motor_init.h that is why i need to use the .o

Comment: Well, i you did you'd still need the .o file, but then this is the way to go, or write your own header file.

Comment: I'm using gcc yes but i also use already created makefiles.
The linker part is of the .mk is:

`# Linker
$(build-exe-y): $(dep-y) $(obj-y) $(os-orti-y) $(sim-y) $(libitem-y) $(ldcmdfile-y)
 @echo
 @echo "  >> LD $@"
 $(do-ld-pre)
$(libitem-y) 
ifeq ($(CROSS_COMPILE)$(COMPILER),gcc)
 $(Q)$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -Xlinker -Map=$(basename $(@F)).map -o $@ $(libpath-y) $(obj-y) $(lib-y) $(libitem-y)`

I don't really know how to change it

Comment: From what it looks like you should probably add `motor_init.o` to you `$(lib-y)` variable somewhere. Or you can just hard-code it right after.